# Subject line when sending a CV via a "Send us your CV" link

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment

I am interested in a company which asks would-be applicants to send their CV via a "Send us your CV" `mailto` link on their website.

My question is simple: do recruiters (or whoever looks at that email) prefer if such emails maintain the subject line set by the `mailto` link or if the subject line is "personalized"?

Personalization is always a nice thing of course, but I'm aware recruiters are frequently overflowing with applications, so perhaps they prefer if such emails stick to the suggested subject line, which would allow the email to be easily categorized and filtered.

Answer (score 5):

IF there is a pre-filled subject then that mail is getting routed by the subject line.  Change it and it will get lost.

Comment: If that's the case, then it sounds like bad form design. The applicant should not be given the opportunity to enter a subject if only one value is acceptable; the form should add the email subject on submission.

Comment: +1. If it's already filled out, leave it like that. Easier tracability. Otherwise I would use something like "CV <FirstName> <LastName>".

Comment: @Mawg would you trust it to be GOOD form design?  I wouldn't

Comment: Depends if I implemented it ;-) One *could* look at it as a form of test  - "would I want to work at  a company that can't even get an email form right?"  :-)

Answer (score 3):

> do recruiters (or whoever looks at that email) prefer if such emails maintain the subject line set by the mailto link or if the subject line is "personalized"?

If they already present a **default subject** header then perhaps it is best to **leave it that way**. Otherwise, if no default placeholder or option is provided feel free to write your own.

As you already thought, they surely have reasons for asking for such specific subject, as for their use internally on the company.

One example of such is *email filters* by subject, which can be used to "filter out" to some folder all applications for faster processing. Changing this may leave you out of such benefit.

Comment: As I commented to the Knight - if that's the case, then it sounds like bad form design. The applicant should not be given the opportunity to enter a subject if only one value is acceptable; the form should add the email subject on submission.

Comment: @Mawg - Do you know the difference between filling out a form on a website, and a link that creates an email in your own email client? The OP is talking about the latter, and although the website link can pre-populate the subject in my email client, they can't block it from being changed.

Comment: OOps! I missed that. In that case, I will double down. The link should be to an address that is solely used for a single purpose (accepting CVs). In either case, it would be bad design on the comapny's fault to do otherwise, lest they lose some applications. I agree, of course, that the OP should not change the suggested subject line, for fear he might fall afoul of the company's potentially sloppy process.